# how to add value to json type column in sub-query

Tags: mysql

I have to combine `recordObj` and `recTime`
I tried `json_insert` function to add `recTime` property in `recordObj` in select statement

It is not returning any records and just giving OK message

**note : I can't change table structure.**

mysql sp:

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `records_get_upcomings`(in p_parent varchar(15))
BEGIN
    WITH RECURSIVE cte (p_parent) AS (
     SELECT child FROM connections WHERE parent = p_parent
     UNION ALL
     SELECT child FROM connections JOIN cte on connections.parent = cte.p_parent
    )
    
   select recordid, `current`, group_concat(past) as past from (
        select * from 
        (
            select cur.recordObj as `current`, past.recordObj as past, cur.recordid as recordid from
            (select recordid, json_insert(recordObj, '$recTime', recTime) as recordObj, rec_status from records inner join cte on records.`from` = cte.p_parent) cur
            cross join 
            (select recordid, json_insert(recordObj, '$recTime', recTime) as recordObj, rec_status from records inner join cte on records.`from` = cte.p_parent and records.`from` = cte.p_parent) past
        where past.rec_status = 1 and cur.rec_status = 0 and past.recordid = cur.recordid
        ) as a
        union 
        (
            select recordObj as `current`, null as past, recordid from records inner join cte on records.`from` = cte.p_parent where rec_status = 0
        )
) as t group by `current`;
END
```

records table :

```
from -> varchar
recordObj -> json
recordid -> varchar
recTime -> datetime
rec_status -> tinyint
u_rec_id -> int
```

any help is appreciated...

Comment: I'm pretty sure your JSON path expressions like `'$recTime'` are not valid. Maybe it should be `'$.recTime'`? There's no way for me to guess, because you don't show the original JSON or what you want the result to be. Anyway, you should review the [manual on JSON paths](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax) to make sure you understand the syntax.

Comment: `recordObj` have two properties `from`, `recoridid` and I wanted `recordObj` which have `recTime`in it so... the syntax was a issue. But can you comment on whether this approach is right or not ? is there any better waly to do it ? And also why it didnt throw any error and gave `OK` message in mysql workbench ?

Comment: I find nearly every use of JSON in SQL would be better if it were done with normal rows and columns instead of JSON.